# Default IP of AWS Codebuild

Tags: docker, aws-codebuild

Our team is trying to use the AWS code-build to run selenium testing. We were able to deploy and up the backend (Gunicorn) and frontend (nginx) and used a custom Docker image. However, we we're not able to access the URL of our Web App.

In my local computer, I was able to use the Docker and access our web app in the default IP of docker-machine (http://192.168.99.100/).

I changed and update the config of frontend to localhost but the selenium testing is still not able to access it in the AWS code build.

Could someone advise what is the default IP of AWS Code Build? Or is it possible to define the default IP address of the AWS Code Build? Thanks

I tried searching AWS documentation for the default IP address of AWS Code Build but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this by running this command:

docker network create -d bridge --subnet 192.168.0.0/0 --gateway 192.168.0.0 dockernet

Comment: This worked great for me.  I ended up putting it in a docker-compose, using a network with an ipam subnet, then assigned an explicit ipv4 address to the container's network.